# Probability: Left Tailed Test

Tags: probability

Any help on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

A study shows that a particular gene lac1 will cause lactose-intolerance in 65% of women that carry the mutation. 15 women are selected to test for the lac1 gene. Results show that out of the 12 women that have lac1, 4 are lactose-intolerant. Can it be concluded, with a significance level = 0.05, that this particular lac1 will result in lactose-intolerance in its carriers 65% of the time? Need to do a left-tailed test.

Comment: It you could edit into your question what you have tried so far, it would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like to be a binomial test and you are looking a one tail test (left..)
(1) First is to construct your hypothesis H0: P_0=0.65 vs H1: P_0 < 0.65;
(2) Then you need to calculate the probability, that among the 12 women who have lac1, what is the probability that there are less and equal to 4 persons (X) of them are lactose-intolerant. This basically says about how rare the event is;
(3) Calculation, P(X<=4)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)
For example, P(X=1)=12*(0.65)^1*(1-0.65)^11 , just a combination calculation;
(4) P(X<=4)=0.027;
(5) so 0.027<0.05, it casts doubt for the H0 hypothesis P0=65%.